# multiples opciones de array en un texto

Tags: php, array, router, concatenación

tengo un array concatenado a un texto, necesito comparar cada elemento para abarcar muchas opciones.

```
$frutas = ['manzana', 'pera', 'naranja', 'platano']
 
switch($uri) {
   case '/frutas/'.$string[]:
      echo $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
      break;
   default:
       echo '404'
       break;
```

pero al ponerlo de esta manera me tira un error "Fatal error: Cannot use [] for reading",
el error me dice que tengo que especificar un elemento de la lista, pero yo necesito que **string** haga referencia a cualquier elemento de la lista, y que cada elemento sea una opcion en la sentencia "switch case".

tambien probre con lo siguiente:

```
$frutas = ['manzana', 'pera', 'naranja', 'platano']

switch($uri) {
   case '/frutas/'.$string[0 || 1 || 2 || 3]:
      echo $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
      break;
   default:
      echo '404'
      break;
```

pero al comparar mas de dos veces me retorna en la pagina 404

Comment: La estructura switch no funciona como planteas. Los case deben estar especificados. Mira https://www.php.net/manual/es/control-structures.switch.php para ver cómo funciona. En tu caso, quizás sea mejor descomponer $uri y cojer el elemento que representa a la fruta, y en un if compararlo con un in_array o array_value_exists

Answer (score 0):

Si he entendido bien tu pregunta, búscas lo siguiente:

Quieres que si cualquiera de las frutas que tienes guardadas en la array $frutas está en la url a la que accede el usuario, se ejecute

```
echo $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
```

Para ello, la solución más rápida que se me ocurre es la siguiente:

```
$frutas = ['manzana', 'pera', 'naranja', 'platano'];
$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$contieneFruta = false;

for ($i = 0; $i < count($frutas); $i++) {
    if (str_contains($uri, $frutas[$i])) {
        $contieneFruta = true;
        break;
    }
}

switch($uri) {
    case $contieneFruta:
        echo $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
        break;
    default:
        echo '404';
}
```

En este código lo primero que hacemos es declarar la array de frutas, a continuación recojemos la URL que pide el usuario, luego, declaramos una variable booleana `$contieneFruta` y la inicializamos como `false`.

Luego utilizamos un `for` para iterar sobre la array buscando si `$uri` contiene la fruta sobre la que estamos iterando (`$frutas[$i]`). En caso de que sí contenga esta `string`, hacemos que la variable `$contieneFruta` sea `true` y realizamos un `break` para no seguir iterando.

Finalmente, dentro del `switch`, miramos el case `$contieneFruta` y realizamos la acción pertinente. Espero que te haya ayudado, seguro que hay una forma más óptima de realizar esto pero así seguro que te funcionará.

Answer (score 0):

Guille, yo resolvería tu problema con un `while` (siempre es más eficiente que un `for`, aunque en este caso tampoco importa tanto porque no son muchos elementos), pero comparando `$uri` con cada elemento del array tal cual (no si lo contiene) porque si no cabría la posibilidad de un valor como `$uri = "frutas/perassssss"`, que sí pasaría un posible corte para después no encontrar la dirección real.

```
$frutas = ['manzana', 'pera', 'naranja', 'platano'];
$uri = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
$contieneFruta = false;
$i = 0;

while ($i < count($frutas) && !$contieneFruta) {
    if ($uri == "frutas/".$frutas[$i]) {
        $contieneFruta = true;
    } else {
        $i++;
    }
}

if ($contieneFruta) {
    echo $uri;
} else {
    echo '404';
}
```

Espero que te sirva